# Power Automate returning 404 instead of empty?

Tags: excel, power-automate

I have a flow set to run the same operations for hundreds of rows of data. I have several "Get a row" Excel steps that I know will fail for most members. I've been handling these with "if" expressions, e.g. if(empty(outputs('Get_a_row')?['body/Example']),'',outputs('Get_a_row')?['body/Example']).

This works fine for most of the fields I pull in the flow. I have three separate "Get a row" operations, of which two work completely fine and the third works fine for every field except one, and that one returns the integer "404" instead of empty for some reason.

I can get around this by just having it ignore a return of 404, but I was hoping someone might have an idea why this one field is behaving differently than the others. It's just an Excel cell like any of the others. The only difference I can think of is that the reference column in the Excel sheet has data validation on it and the other columns don't, but I don't see why that should matter when the 404 is occurring when the flow fails to pull that row in the first place.

**Edit**

Here are some screenshots. The first shows the flow editor. The second is a run that failed because outputs('Get_a_row')?['body/Status'] returns an integer (404), which empty() cannot read. #3 shows success when I change it to empty(string()), but is not the output I want. #4 shows success in the way I want when I change it to equals(outputs,404) because I'm forcing it to ignore the 404, but I still don't understand why that single field is returning 404 when the others aren't. It's not like it's the first column in the spreadsheet or anything.

[image: Flow editor]

[image: Run 1, fails because empty() doesn't expect an integer (404)]

[image: Run 2, succeeds because I changed it to empty(string()) but returns 404]

[image: Run 3, I changed it to if(equals([output],404),'',[output]) so it would actually return null if the row failed to return]

Comment: Wait, I'm so dumb. It's because the column title, "Status," coincides with the 404 status message. Disregard, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to a kind stranger asking me to post screenshots, so long live screenshots and kind strangers. It's because the column title in question, "Status," coincides with the "status" of 404 output in the body. Oops!